# Is it normal than my $http request get resolved in inverse order? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I have a function inside a service that makes $http.get request from an array

```
var ids = [1,2,3]
var extensionPromises = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < extensions.length ; i++) {

        var myPromise = myHttpService.getOneExtension(ids[i]);
        extensionPromises.push(myPromise);
    }

return $q.when(
        Promise.all(extensionPromises).then(function(all){

            $rootScope.$broadcast("allReady");
            return true;
        }).catch(function(error){
            var e = {};
            e.error = error;
            e.error.type = "http.get";
            return (e);
        })
);
```

That send the ID to a simple `$http.get( myUrl + id).then()...`, all work ok but when I see the XHR get info in the console, it resolves in the inverse order, that is 3, 2, 1.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no guarantees on order of resolve of multiple async requests. They are subject to network time, server time etc. Even 2 requests to same endpoint may not return in same order they were sent

Comment: I kind of thinked that too, but I get the same result always and is just weird...

Comment: also no need to use `Promise.all` inside `$q.when` ...can use `$q.all()`